# Добавление символов в html при нажатии соответствующих кнопок

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Пробую сделать калькулятор. Сделал интерфейс и приступил к написанию функционала. При нажатии на кнопки калькулятора на его табло выводится цифра в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, однако цифры заменяют друг друга при каждом нажатии вместо того чтобы добавляться по очереди объединяясь в одно число.
1) Как сделать чтобы они добавлялись друг к другу? 
2) Как можно ограничить длинну получаемого числа до определенного количества знаков?

```js
$(function() {

$('.button').click(function(){
$('.calcIn').html(this.value).html();
})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="simpleCalc">

  <div class="scoreboard">
   <div class="calcIn" id="text"></div>
  </div>
  <table>
   <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn testclass" value="7">
   <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn" value="8">
   <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn" value="9">
   <br>
   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn" value="4">
   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn" value="5">
   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn" value="6">
      <br>
   <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn" value="1">
   <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn" value="2">
   <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn" value="3">
      <br>
   <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn" value=",">
   <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn" value="0">

  </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем переменную numbers, в нее прибавляем(не складываем) число. Выводим переменную numbers.

Делаем проверку на кол-во символов в переменной функцией `length >= 10` и возращаем

```js
$(function() {
  var numbers = 0;
  $('.button').click(function() {
    if (numbers.length >= 10) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (numbers == 0) {
        numbers = this.value;
      } else {
        numbers += this.value;
      }
    }

    $('.calcIn').text(numbers);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="simpleCalc">

      <div class="scoreboard">
       <div class="calcIn" id="text"></div>
      </div>
      <table>
       <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn testclass" value="7">
       <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn" value="8">
       <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn" value="9">
       <br>
       <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn" value="4">
       <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn" value="5">
       <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn" value="6">
          <br>
       <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn" value="1">
       <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn" value="2">
       <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn" value="3">
          <br>
       <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn" value=",">
       <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn" value="0">

      </table>
     </div>
```